# Fetching @ManyToOne entity more than one returns String representation, Why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I found a weird issue in my Spring Data JPA application. I don't know why but when I am fetching records having `@ManyToOne` entity, it returns its instance only once in the response and then only String representation subsequently. Following are the Entity and response respectively:
**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_survey")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Survey.class)
public class Survey {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "survey_type", nullable = false)
  private SurveyType surveyType;
  //.... Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_survey_type")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name", scope = SurveyType.class)
public class SurveyType {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;
  //.... Getters & Setters
}
```

Following is the JSON response when fetching `Survey`.

```
"surveyType": {
        "name": "SF",
        "description": "Some description here"
    },
```

and then:

```
    "surveyType": "SF",
```

if there are multiple instance of `surveyType` in the Survey Response. Why it represent it as String rather than object after 1st attempt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a result of using `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

By using that annotation, you're telling it that the response should include one fully serialized instance and subsequently return IDs referring to that fully serialized instance.

Comment: Oh yes.. that was the root cause. awesome Thanks

Comment: after adding `generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class` it resolved my issue